# Enabling SQL Server stored procedure debugging from .Net Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I saw many Q&A's online that explain how to enable debugging SQL Server stored procedures but they appliy to non-Core .NET e.g. .NET 3.5 etc. I am trying to debug into a stored procedure from a C# .Net Core library but I cannot make it work at all. Any ideas how to do it?